# MySQL use running total to select records

Tags: mysql

I have a query that shows running total in the last column

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT
    q1.REC_IDX , q1.PAL_IDX, q1.ORD,q1. REPL,
q1.LOCATION, q1.COUNT, q1.WEIGHT, q1.LOAD_OUT, q1.DOCK, q1.PULL_THRU, q1.LINE, q1.PRE_PAL, q1.QTY_REMAIN,q1. USED, q1.BULK_EST,

   (@runtot := @runtot + q1.COUNT) AS rt
   
   
FROM
(SELECT REC_IDX , PAL_IDX, ORD, REPL,
LOCATION, COUNT, WEIGHT, LOAD_OUT, DOCK, PULL_THRU, LINE, PRE_PAL, QTY_REMAIN, USED, BULK_EST

FROM PALLETS

LEFT JOIN RACKS
ON RACKS.RACK_ID = PALLETS.LOCATION

WHERE LOAD_OUT = '4R' 

HAVING (COALESCE(COUNT,0)+COALESCE(PALLETS.BULK_EST,0)) - (COALESCE( PALLETS.USED,0))  > 0 

ORDER BY COALESCE(REPL, 1000) ASC, ORD) as q1
```

[image]

The results show the records in the correct order and the running total properly adding up based one the order criteria.

The last piece I need is a condition that will only return records where the running total has a value that fulfills a preset amount. For example 110.

So the result would be limited to the first 3 rows since the running total in the third row is <= to 110.

I have not been able to figure out that last piece.

Comment: Shown output does not match the query text. *a condition that will only return records where the running total has a value that fulfills a preset amount* Add according HAVING

Comment: You are correct there are more columns. For clarity purposes I only copied columns pertaining to the question. 

I tries HAVING but did not work. Where would you add that.

Comment: Provide complete reproduceable example - CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO + desired output for this data + detailed explanations.